# codeblocks dll kill process every 20sec

Tags: c++, dll, process, codeblocks

I want to refresh or kill process every 20 seconds or something like that
here is code :

```
void KillProcessByName(const char *filename)
{
HANDLE hSnapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, NULL);
 PROCESSENTRY32 pEntry;
pEntry.dwSize = sizeof (pEntry);
BOOL hRes = Process32First(hSnapShot, &pEntry);
while (hRes)
{
if (strcmp(pEntry.szExeFile, filename) == 0)
    {
        HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE, 0,
                                      (DWORD) pEntry.th32ProcessID);
        if (hProcess != NULL)
        {
            TerminateProcess(hProcess, 9);
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
        }
    }
    hRes = Process32Next(hSnapShot, &pEntry);
}
CloseHandle(hSnapShot);
}
int main()
{
killProcessByName("Notepad.exe");
return 0;
}
```

.....................

Comment: What's your question ?  If the code does not work what was the test, what did you see, what did you expect.  If the code does not compile what were the errors ?

Comment: @RichardCritten hey .. Whats errors there ? there no errors with me .. i just want to call/refresh/timer something to keep checking if process is still running

Comment: Put the call in an infinite loop with a 20 second Sleep.

Comment: @RichardCritten isn't it sleep Freeze my application ?

Comment: Not if the kill loop is in another thread.

Comment: @user4581301 how it should be ?